# How to automatically forward specific user's messages from channel A to channel B in telegram?

Tags: python, telegram

I'm looking for possible approaches on telegram messages forwarding automation. Let's assume there's user Bob in private telegram group A (I, as an user am also in that group), and private group B. Bob is sharing some useful information, but there are hundreds of people spamming inside, so I need to automatically, 24h/7 forward only his messages to my private group B. Have you got any ideas how could I approach this problem?

I was searching for some solutions and found telethon library, but couldn't find methods that would satisfy my requirements (perhaps it's because of my lack of experience in this library). Would be grateful for any ideas!

Comment: What have you tried to do with the help of the library? Share the code snippet that you tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.